# Inserting hexadecimal value as integer to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, hex

I have a MySQL table where a field have a type of INT.
In my Python script I am reading the hexadecimal value (0xc558, for example) and trying to insert this value in the table as INT field type.

Doing so gives me:

`(1265, "Data truncated for column at row 1`)

An INT field type should be a standard integer with 4 bytes which should accept the value of 0xC558, which is 50520 in a decimal world.

I'm not doing any conversion, and the code I use is:

```
self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(NULL, %s)", (dataDict["hex_value"],)
```

where dataDict["hex_value"] is 0xC558.

Trying to use `int(dataDict["hex_value"])` also gives an error: `Invalid literal for int() with base 10: 0xC558`.

Trying to use `int(dataDict["hex_value"],base=16)` also gives an error: `int() can't convert non-string with explicit base`.

EDIT: the value is of type 'str', as `print type(dataDict["hex_value"])` shows `(type 'str')`

Comment: what `type` is `dataDict['hex_value']`?

Comment: what happens if you just `print(dataDict['hex_value'])`

Comment: Thanks. What does `repr(dataDict['hex_value'])` give you?

Comment: If it is `str` I wonder why on earth you get the exception when you do: `int(dataDict["hex_value"],base=16)`

Comment: MySQL hex literals use the syntax `X'C558'`, not `0xC558`. So it's treating that value as a string, not a hex number. I suggest you convert it to an integer in Python before doing the `INSERT`.

Comment: @Barmar, you nailed it. I was trying to convert that during the query execution. When I converted the value right after reading, everything was OK. Thank you and Paulo Bu.

Comment: OK, if the type is `str` why don't you print out the value and remove all suspense? That way we might stand a chance of explaining the error! (Sorry, the answer was just provided).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
int(dataDict["hex_value"][2:], base=16)
```

The substring `[2:]` extracts the part of the string after the `0x` prefix. More completely:

```
self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(NULL, %s)", (int(dataDict["hex_value"][2:], base=16), ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that you AREN'T trying to insert a string or an integer.

You say "dataDict["hex_value"] is 0xC558" but you don't say whether it's a string or (as the absence of quotation marks would imply) an integer. It can't be an integer because of the first error you replt. It's clearly not a string due to the second error.

So the issue lies with the type of whatever you have stored in `dataDict`, and you don't shoe the code for that. Yet ...

Comment: Probably. I was going to edit it, but with an acceptable answer in place maybe I should just delete it?

Comment: I don't think anyone really sees it as that helpful, and despite the upvote I would be happy to let it go (since the real answer was nothing to do with the data types).